# cannot access phpmyadmin in wamp

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I've tried all of the previous answers to this question.

This is what my code looks like:

```
 Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have no clue what's going on, my other machine allows me to use phpmyadmin

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Please edit you question to include that.

Comment: There are two different version numbers in your code. 4.1.14 and 3.4.5

Answer (score 1):

This line in your `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
```

Should be

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
```

to match the previous alias statement.

It is also more secure to use a config something like this

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
       # and if you want access from other PC on your internal network
       Allow from 192.168.0
</Directory>
```

This assumes your subnet starts with these 3 quartiles 192.168.0, if yours is different amend it accordingly.

The `Allow from all` can be dangerous if you decide to open up your router to allow access from the internet, it gives access to phpmyadmin to the world. *Not usually a good idea*.